# How to adjust axis labels in a graph?

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

I can't understand why I can't adjust my x-axis labels.

I have been trying to use the following code but it is not working well.

```
x1 <- c(80, 5, 8)
x2 <- c(70, 0, 25)

plot(x1, type="o",col="red", xlab="cluster", ylab="Percent", 
     main="GDP vs Population", pch =17)
text(seq(1, 10, by=1), par("usr")[3] - 0.2, 
     labels=c("Cluster 1", "Cluster 2", "Cluster 3"), xpd=TRUE)
lines(x2, type="o", col="blue", pch =19)
legend("topright", 
       legend=c("GDP", "Population"), 
       col=c("red", "blue"), 
       pch=c(17,19), 
       bty="n", 
       pt.cex=1, 
       cex=1, 
       text.col="black", 
       horiz=F , 
       inset=c(0.1, 0.1))
```

That is what I have:

[image: my graph]

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `mtext`. First, switch off automatic x axis using `xaxt="n"`. Second, rebuild it at `1:3` using `axis` for the tick marks, and `mtext` for the labels.

```
plot(x1,type="o",col="red", xlab="cluster", ylab="Percent", 
     main="GDP vs Population", pch =17, xaxt="n")
lines(x2, type="o", col="blue", pch =19)
axis(side=1, at=1:3, labels=paste("cluster", 1:3))
legend("topright", 
       legend=c("GDP", "Population"), 
       col=c("red", "blue"), 
       pch=c(17,19), 
       bty="n", 
       pt.cex=1, 
       cex=1, 
       text.col="black", 
       horiz=F , 
       inset=c(0.1, 0.1))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
x1 <- c(80, 5, 8)
x2 <- c(70, 0, 25)
```